# JSF Memory Leak

Tags: java, spring, jsf, memory-leaks, richfaces

I am using **JSF**, **Richfaces** and **Spring** to build my web-app.

I have a problem. The memory usage of the server always goes up and never comes down even if the session is timed-out or is destroyed **("The user logged out")**
and it's keeps going up until the **system is crashed** .

The wired thing is that when the same user with the same IP logs in again, the memory never goes up by the same old rate, for which I suppose that the memory is keeping the session even after the **logout** or when the session is **timed out** .

Please can anyone help me with this issue !?

Comment: What do you see when you memory profile your application to see what is leaking?

Comment: actually I didn't profile my application
I use the terminal to check the memory every time I login or logout
My thoughts is that the sessions are never expires in tomcat server memory

Comment: In my experience, without a measuring with a profiler, you can only guess what could be wrong.

Comment: Either use a profiler, or use jmap to take a memory dump at the moment you have already leaked a lot of memory. This dump can then be analyzed with the Eclipse Memory Analyzer.

Comment: I already took a memory dump and analyzed it but I found that My instances are good in counting and size.
If you could tell me another way to dump the memory and make a good meaning of it I will be thankful

Comment: Use jvisualvm and check number of objects. Problem can be in other part of application server. See [usage page](http://visualvm.java.net/gettingstarted.html)

Comment: Ok i will try all of those But I want to add another thing to you info
I debugged my app and I got a hold on the session and I saw that there is a variable called expiring which its value is false.
could this be changed in anyways ?!

Comment: I agree with @ajozwik, jvisualvm, once you learn it, is a great tool in hunting down memory leaks (hint: check finding biggest objects by retained size).

Answer (score 0):

i have used JProfiler and yourkit but i am not satisfied with output for actual performance tuning and memory usage currently we have been switched to [java melody](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/). This not only help performance optimization in dev but also in production system. Java melody is very easy to integrate and configure and in production you can enable or disable by just updating web.xml